# Is Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel included in .NET Framework?

Tags: c#, interop

I'm referencing this assembly in order to export Excel files but I don't see the .dll in my binaries.

I know that if I set `Embed Interop Types` to `False` I can set the `Copy Local`  to `True`. But what I want to know is, what if the end user doesn't have Excel installed on his computer?

If he is not able to export, can I solve that by providing the .dll? Or this assembly is already included in the .NET Framework?

Thank you.

Comment: are you familiar with adding references ?

Comment: ... and/or with following the step-by-step instructions given my Microsoft? -> http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302084

Answer (score 3):

A reference will need to be added and the end user will need to have a way to interact with the Microsoft Office calls in order to use the calls.

The same goes for developing on a workstation with office and then deploying to a server that does not have the office suite. It is good habit to avoid using those just because you never know what you will be allowed to move/install to the "live" environment when the time comes.

You can however have your program write the file in xml and save it with a .xls extension. This is a little more work but will allow the code to run and will allow users with Excel to open.

[Using xml to format the file](http://www.addictivetips.com/microsoft-office/excel-2010-working-with-xml-format/)